# CSS - Select all table cells <td> or <th> in a table

Tags: html, css

I want to style all table cells with background-color:blue, when they are inside a table with class="p1". The following works, but it is long:

```
table.p1 > tbody > tr > td,
table.p1 > thead > tr > td,
table.p1 > tbody > tr > th,
table.p1 > thead > tr > th{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Is there a shorter/more elegant way to define this CSS rule?

Edit: only the table cells immediately contained by table "p1" may be styled, and no further children (such as nested tables inside those cells)

Comment: i don't think so but you could omit the child selector `table.p1 td, table.p1 th { background-color: blue; }`

Comment: @MichaelCoker I can only have the style apply to cells that belong to the table with class="p1", your solution would also style any cell that may be in nested tables within the master table

Comment: this question isn't really on topic here, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok then put that in the post. the new post on codereview

Comment: I get the need to ensure you don't target nested tables.  CSS doesn't offer a concise version.  Would be great if you could specify a single rule like this: `table.p1 > (thead|tbody|tfoot) > tr > (th|td) { }` [does not work - example only] !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out a much shorter version. I remembered that you can use asterisk * for any element. Knowing that the table tag may only immediately contain tbody/thead, and tr may only immediately contain td/th, I revised the CSS class to the following:

```
.p1 > * > tr > * {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: `table.p1 > * > tr > *` this would mean even the text gets the background color i suppose?

Comment: @Syfer the TD or TH elements contained within the TR element will be styled. [tr > *] means "select all immediate children of the table row", and since the only children that a table row can have are TD and TH elements, it will style only the TD or TH elements

Comment: how about `.p1 tr *`?

Comment: @Syfer that would also style any cell that may be in nested tables within the master table, which I can't allow

Comment: Again, .p1 > tr > * > * is better. table is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Three things I'd fix:

1. `table.p1` is overly specific. This isn't a best practice.
2. I would consider including "table" in the class name so its meaning is obvious.
3. The `tbody`, `thead`, and `tr` levels are unecessary, unless you plan on nesting `td`'s.

   `.table-p1 td, .table-p1 th  {
       background-color:blue;
   }`

Edit: Given the updated nesting requirement to the question, I would propose creating two table classes:

`.table-normal td, .table-normal th { background-color: grey; }`

`.table-p1 td, .table-p1 th { background-color: blue; }`

Then you could just add the `.table-normal` class for nested tables inside `.table-p1` and avoid all these fancy, brittle selectors.

Comment: class="p1" is just an example name.

Comment: the elements tbody and thead are automatically added by browsers, even when you omit them in tables, so I have to account for them in my CSS class or else it won't work

Comment: Right. This example doesn't use the > direct child selector, so it would catch any and all td's, no matter whether they were in a thead, tbody, trow, or a .frozen-monkey.

Comment: @user3163495, your question isn't obvious that you don't wish the styles to apply to nested tables, in which case David would be right that you don't need the `tbody`, `thead` and `tr` levels in your CSS selector. `.p1 td, .p1 th { ... }` is the selector your question implies you want.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your requirement, that you need to use the direct children selector, then i don't believe there is any way you can do it. You can remove the white spaces in-between but that is about it. Only other way is to add a specific class name to the cells you want to target...

Comment: I was able to find a solution, see the answer I provided